# You know what probably happened?

Tags: grammar, connotations

> You know what probably happened? Somebody must have stolen my credit card.

I have seen the above sentences from a textbook.

**Question 1**

According to a textbook, "You know what probably happened?" implies "I think something probably happened." Is this right?

**Question 2**

Also, in this case, nobody is 100% sure that somebody stole my credit card. Thus, I cannot say something like the following.

> You know what would probably have happened? Somebody must have stolen my credit card.

"Would have <p.p.>" governs subjunctive usage about a past event, so this is improper. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Yes,

*You know what probably happened?* implies *I think something probably happened*

because

- You know *xyz*?

basically means

- I am about to tell you [more about] *xyz*.

(and *xyz* implies *I think xyz* from the speaker's viewpoint, as in *roses are red* implies *I think roses are red*)

(Note: the implication is not a strict logical implication, because the speaker could say *You know what probably happened? Nothing.*)

2/ You are correct in thinking you cannot say that. You are using the conditional perfect (*would have happened*), which is normally used to describe counterfactual situations. The following clause with *must*, however, is clearly **not** describing a counterfactual situation from the speaker's viewpoint, hence the grammatical clash.

Comment: Hello, @legatrix I have one further question. If I intent to express 'conjecture', Do I need to say something like; <You know what I think probably happened?> or <You know what would probably happen?> (maybe this "would" is for back-shifting?)

Comment: However, according to your feedback, just simply saying <You know what probably happened> can express 'conjecture' by itself, am I right? As an ESL learner, I believed <You know what I think probably happened> is better though.

Comment: I tihnk they both express a conjecture equally well. The difference is not semantic, it is mainly stylistic---the 'I think' just softens the conjecture a bit. It is already clear that the first sentence is a conjecture because of the 'probably'.

Comment: Your other suggestion "You know what would probably happen?" is not correct in this context. For more details, I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: HI again @legatrix I have posted my new question. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270494/my-understanding-you-know-what-probably-happened-and-others/270496#270496